# Sample size needed to validate classification/prediction model

Tags: classification, predictive-models, sample-size, validation

Dose any rule of thumb exist (or possible calculation) regarding sample size needed to validate an binary classification model.

We have developed this prediction model for a medical condition and would like to validate it in new cohort, but we don’t know how to estimate how many events/patients needed for this.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question? If so, how did you do your sample size calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer Riley s article on sample size calculation for external validation studies. The rule of thumb is you need at least 100 events per predictor parameter for external validation studies